# Class method changing all variables of that class Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm trying to create a class then have categories which I can deposit and withdraw from. The issue I'm having is that when I take say food for example and call the method 'deposit', it also updates for the object named 'Clothing'. I'm sure this is a simple fix.

The output for the below code is:

```
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'Initial1'}, {'amount': 500, 'description': 'Initial2'}]
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'Initial1'}, {'amount': 500, 'description': 'Initial2'}]
Clothing Food
```

Whereas I want:

```
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'Initial1'}]
[{'amount': 500, 'description': 'Initial2'}]
Clothing Food
```

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks

```
class Category:
    ledger=list()
    runningBalance=int()
    name=""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    
    def deposit(self,amount,description):
        self.ledger.append({"amount":amount,"description":description})
        self.runningBalance=self.runningBalance+amount

Food=Category("Food")
Clothing=Category("Clothing")

Food.deposit(1000,"Initial1")
Clothing.deposit(500,"Initial2")

print(Food.ledger)
print(Clothing.ledger)

print(Clothing.name,Food.name)
```

Comment: That's the difference between class attributes and instance attributes: the former are shared amount all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the class variables object variables.

```
class Category:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.ledger=list()
        self.runningBalance=int()
    
    def deposit(self,amount,description):
        self.ledger.append({"amount":amount,"description":description})
        self.runningBalance=self.runningBalance+amount

Food=Category("Food")
Clothing=Category("Clothing")

Food.deposit(1000,"Initial1")
Clothing.deposit(500,"Initial2")

print(Food.ledger)
print(Clothing.ledger)

print(Clothing.name,Food.name)
```

Output:

```
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'Initial1'}]
[{'amount': 500, 'description': 'Initial2'}]
Clothing Food
```